# How to open a box on screen by clicking a link and hide it when clicked outside in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, tablet

My goal is to have `#box2` appear when I click on `#box1` but when you click on something other than `#box2`, it will display none and only `#box1` will show.

Here are my 2 boxes, they are just 2 styled divs:

```js
 var condition;


 $(document).click(function() {

   if (condition === 'block') {
     $(":not(#box2)").click(function() {
       $("#box2").hide();
     });
   }

 })



 $('#box1').click(function(e) {
   $('#box2').css('display', 'block');
   condition = 'block';
 });

 $('#box2').click(function(e) {
   $('#box2').css('display', 'none');
   condition = 'none';
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box1" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: red; margin-left: 100px; margin-bottom: 50px; position: absolute;">
</div>



<div id="box2" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: blue; margin-left: 150px; display: none; position: absolute;">
</div>
```

This current code works correctly the first time but after that, it wont run again. I am just wondering if there is a reset function or where I am going wrong?

Really what I want to do is make this work on an ipad so when the user clicks/taps away from the box, it will close. If there are better ways to do this on the Ipad tablet, please let me know!!

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't nest click events

Comment: Should I use $(document).ready instead?

Comment: Isn't it enough?: `$(document).on('click', function (e) {
   $('#box2').toggle(!!$(e.target).closest('#box1').length);
});` https://jsfiddle.net/rdrg8uLj/  I'm not sure what is your expected behaviour on clicking box2

Comment: I think the title of the question should change into something like: 'How to open a box on screen by clicking a link and hide it when clicked outside in JavaScript'

Comment: True, I kinda asked 2 different questions. All set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't overcomplicate things. This is all the javascript you need, get rid of everything else:

```
$(document).click(function () {
    $('#box2').hide();
});

$('#box1').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#box2').show();
});
```

Comment: The downside is that you are stopping event propagation, meaning it won't be possible to delegate any click event for box1 descendant to any box1 ancestor

Comment: Thank you Damon! This works well on the Ipad as well. There is so much I still have to learn about JS, I will take your don't over complicate comments to heart!

Answer (score 4):

You could just filter event target at document level:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  $('#box2').toggle(!!$(e.target).closest('#box1').length);
});
```

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: This is an elegant solution +1

Comment: Thank you Wolf for your solution. I think I will use this one for my desktop website. Its works great but does not mimic the same behavior on ipad.

Comment: It should work the same on ipad, so 'im not sure how do you test it

Comment: I use a website called BrowserStack.com it emulates most of the platforms and you can test on your chosen device there.

Comment: Oh ya but none emulator can replicate exact device behaviour. So you should test it on true ipad device instead alhough i'm not sure this is just an emulator issue

Comment: Ahh I see. I definitely will once I have this feature finished!

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to all `click` events of the `document` and then use the `event.target` to detect which element is being clicked. if the clicked element is `box1` and `box2` is not being shown then display it to the user. in any other condition we can hide the `box2` if it's not the element being clicked. here is the vanilla JavaScript code to achieve this:

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id='box1'>BOX ONE</div>
  <div id='box2' style="display: none;">BOX TWO</div>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      var secondBox = document.getElementById('box2')
      if(event.target.id === 'box1' && secondBox.style.display === 'none'){
        secondBox.style.display = 'block'
      } else if (event.target.id !== 'box2') {
        secondBox.style.display = 'none'
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And if you are into DRY (Do not repeat yourself), you can define a function for this task. Take look at this modified version of the script:

```
function addOpenHandler(handler, target){
  document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if(event.target === handler && target.style.display === 'none'){
      target.style.display = 'block'
    } else if (event.target !== target) {
      target.style.display = 'none'
    }
  })
}

addOpenHandler( document.getElementById('box1'), document.getElementById('box2') )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).click(function () {
        if (condition === 'block')
        {
            $(":not(#box2)").click(function () {
                $("#box2").hide();
            });
        }
    })
```

The line `$("#box2").hide();` is firing after every click

Comment: Thank you Joe, I see that now!